# ¿porque la BD mongo no me trae los datos correctamente, solo undefined?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial para hacer un chat con Nodejs y MongoDb, ya esta funcionando solo que los chats guardados solo dice undefined,este es el metodo para salvar los datos en la BD, la cual si creo la base de datos pero no inserta ningun dato

```
var newMsg=new Chat({msg,nick: socket.nickname});
await newMsg.save();
```

Chat es el modelo, se supone que deben salir los chats viejos, pero me da el siguiente error :

> undefined:undefined

Comment: Puedes verificar mediante un console.log que newMsg antes de ejecutar la funcion save() si haya tomado los valores correctos  de mensaje y nick.

Comment: Leyendo tu código veo lo siguiente: *`{msg,nick:`*, ¿puedes verificar que sea un error de tipeo? Debería ser: *`{msg.nick:`*. Estás usando una coma en donde debería ir un punto. Saludos